# Layout issue with HTML and CSS - Cannot move div snuggly to new position due to height of other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with the layout of my HTML

It currently looks like, which is desired:

[image]

However, it is possible that more text will be addled to the middle right box (the one starts with "I will grow with content"). When his happens, I'd like the bottom right box (the one starting with "The important bit") to appear snuggly under the left menu.

The issue I have is although it moves under the left menu, it is not snug.

Within the JSFiddle below, there is a line of comments, if you uncomment it, you'll see the issue (screen shot). As you can also see, I'd like the box to start as shown by the blue arrow.

[image]

JS FIDDLE : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uC6dH/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myContainer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Left menu</p>
    <p>Left menu</p>
    <p>Left menu</p>
    <p>Left menu</p>
    <p>Left menu</p>
    <p>Left menu</p>
    <p>Left menu</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>My heading - fine as is, a fixed size based upon content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>I will grow with content in some situations! If I get really big (greater height), then the box below (called important bit) should fit snuggly under Left menu</p>
    <p><!--I am more content which is not predicatble... Ha ha ha ha ha, I have destroyed this wonderfully layout design. Next step, the world! --></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>The important bit. I want to appear under left menu, but I don't. There is a big old margin between me and the Left menu </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myContainer
{ 
    width:420px;
    float:left;
}

.box{
    float:left;
    border:solid;
    width:200px;
}
```

Can this be done with only HTML and CSS (meaning, no JS/Jquery/scripting language of any sort etc)?

Comment: You can use plugin like isotope or masonry for make this. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ - http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I can write this with Javascript easily, but the problem is, as per my question @JoffreyMaheo, I have to use HTML and CSS. Thank you for the link though, seems like a useful tool

Comment: I bet you cannot do that just using HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be the solution you are looking for! http://jsfiddle.net/aq2vr/

html

```
<div class="myContainer">

<div class="boxLeft">
    <p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p>
</div>

<div class="boxRight">
    <p>My heading - fine as is, a fixed size based upon content</p>
</div>

<div class="boxRight">
    <p>I will grow with content in some situations! If I get really big (greater height), then the box below (called important bit) should fit snuggly under Left menu</p><p><  I am more content which is not predicatble... Ha ha ha ha ha, I have destroyed this wonderfully layout design. Next step, the world! --></p>
</div>

<div class="boxLeft">
    <p>The important bit. I want to appear under left menu, but I don't. There is a big old margin between me and the Left menu </p>
</div>
```

css

```
.myContainer
{ 
  width:440px; // increased the width to 440px to accomodate the extra margin in the objects now. You can adjust the margins and widths of the objects to bring this back down to 420px if you wish.
  float:left;
}

.boxRight
{
  float:right; // any boxes you want to stay in the right column
  border:solid;
  width:200px;
  //position:relative; //Position:relative; and left:-14px is for realigning the columns
  //left:-14px;        //to the container box so that they do not have any space between the container and themselves.
}

.boxLeft
{
  float:left; // any boxes you want to display in the left column.
  border:solid;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:14px; // for re-aligning the boxes in the right column when it does not overflow
  //position:relative; //Position:relative; and left:-14px is for realigning the columns
  //left:-14px;        //to the container box so that they do not have any space between the container and themselves.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the boxes on the right, float right.

There is a minor layout issue but that is easy to fix so I wont correct it.

http://jsfiddle.net/uC6dH/11/

```
<div class="myContainer">

    <div class="box">
        <p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p><p>Left menu</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
        <p>My heading - fine as is, a fixed size based upon content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
        <p>I will grow with content in some situations! If I get really big (greater height), then the box below (called important bit) should fit snuggly under Left menu</p><p><  I am more content which is not predicatble... Ha ha ha ha ha, I have destroyed this wonderfully layout design. Next step, the world! --></p>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
        <p>The important bit. I want to appear under left menu, but I don't. There is a big old margin between me and the Left menu </p>
    </div>
</div>

.myContainer
{ 
    width:420px;
    float:left;
}

.box{
    float:left;
    border:solid;
    width:200px;
}

.box2{
    float:right;
    border:solid;
    width:200px;
}
```